# Azure ServiceBus weird behavior of IMessageReciever.receiveBatch()

Tags: java, azure, concurrency, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm dealing with an Azure Service Bus Subscription and its Dead Letter Queue in Java SpringBoot setup.
I need to process the messages in DLQ when there is a trigger.
I have 12 messages in the DLQ, I need to read 5 messages in one go and submit it to an ExecutorService to process the individual messages.
I created an `IMessageReceiver deadLetterReceiver`, then did batch receiving as `deadLetterReceiver.receiveBatch(5)`
The catch here is until the messages in 1st batch are not processed, the next batch of messages is not read, and the 1st batch of messages will not be removed from DLQ, and it remains there.
The problem is after I process the 1st batch and read the 2nd batch from the ASB, instead of getting the next 5 messages, I get the same messages again.

For example; if I have messages with messageId 1 to 12 in DLQ, after reading the 1st batch, I get messages with messageId 1,2,3,4,5. After reading the second batch instead of getting 6,7,8,9,10 I'm getting 1,2,3,4,5.

Here is the code:

```
public void processDeadLetterQueue(){
 IMessageReceiver deadLetterReceiver = getDeadLetterMessageReceiver();
 Long deadLetterMessageCount = getDeadLetterMessageCount();
 Long receivedMessageCount = 0L;
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
 
 while(receivedMessageCount < deadLetterMessageCount) {
  Collection<IMessage> messageList = deadLetterReceiver.receiveBatch(5);
  receivedMessageCount += messageList.size();
  List<Callable<Void>> callableDeadLetterMessages = new ArrayList<>();
  messageList.forEach(message ->callableDeadLetterMessages.add(() -> {
   handleDeadLetterMessage(message, deadLetterReceiver);
   return null;
  }));
  try {
   List<Future<Void>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(callableDeadLetterMessages);
    for (Future<Void> future : futureList) {
     future.get(); 
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex){
     log.error("Interrupted during processing callableDeadLetterMessage: ", ex);
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
 }
 executor.shutdown(); 
 deadLetterReceiver.close();
}
```

How can I stop it reading the same message again in the next batch and read the next available messages instead?

Note: I' not abandoning the message from DLQ (`deadLetterReceiver.abandon(message.getLockToken());`)

Comment: I use the SequenceNumber to get batches of messages. e.g. in C# fromSequenceNumber = (int)serviceBusMessages.Last().SequenceNumber + 1; If you don't use the SequenceNumber it will just get the first set of messages as they still exist in the DLQ as you haven't deleted them

Comment: @codebrane can you please provide a sample example or documentation for this ? I'm unable to find .Last() in java API docs